# Bundle Install Errors

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I am taking the App Academy Open course and have come to an issue with a project.  I am trying to install the Gems needed to use RSPEC but am getting an error when installing the bundler.

Here is my attempt to install.

```
mkremeier@DESKTOP-QTDVHIG:/mnt/c/Users/micha/OneDrive/Documents/Code/rspec_exercise_1$ bundle install
```

Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Resolving dependencies...
Using bundler 2.1.4
Following files may not be writable, so sudo is needed:
  /usr/local/bin
  /var/lib/gems/2.5.0
  /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/build_info
  /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/cache
  /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/doc
  /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/extensions
  /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems
  /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/specifications
Fetching byebug 11.1.3

Your user account isn't allowed to install to the system RubyGems.
  You can cancel this installation and run:

```
  bundle install --path vendor/bundle
```

to install the gems into ./vendor/bundle/, or you can enter your password
  and install the bundled gems to RubyGems using sudo.

Password:
Installing byebug 11.1.3 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
current directory: /tmp/bundler20200521-509-1g7fh3zbyebug-11.1.3/gems/byebug-11.1.3/ext/byebug
```

/usr/bin/ruby2.5 -r ./siteconf20200521-509-1opspqa.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/bundler20200521-509-1g7fh3zbyebug-11.1.3/gems/byebug-11.1.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /tmp/bundler20200521-509-1g7fh3zbyebug-11.1.3/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.5.0/byebug-11.1.3/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing byebug (11.1.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install byebug -v '11.1.3' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  byebug

Answer (score 2):

After doing some more digging I found the solution was running

```
sudo aptAinstall ruby-dev
```

then running

```
bundle install
```

Answer (score 0):

> can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

It seems that you're missing some necessary header files there, you can check the [ByeBug documentation](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/byebug/11.1.1) to find out which ones are needed.

Are you on Linux or macOS?

Comment: I’m using Windows 10 with a Ubuntu subsystem. I’m super new to this.